# WiX bundle failing to run exe as administrator

Tags: c#, wpf, permissions, wix

I am trying to force a WPF exe triggered by a WiX bundle to run as admin because it needs to be able to restart a service. Before anyone asks why this is running in a separate exe, sadly I do not have time to learn how to build a custom bootstrapper.

So far I have tried adding an app.manifest file to the exe with this line:

```
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

When that didn't work I went over the exepackage in the bundle to check that it was configured to run as admin (PerMachine should run it as elevated):

```
      <ExePackage Id="MMAConfigure" 
              DisplayName="Configuring Microsoft Monitoring Agent" 
              Compressed="yes" 
              PerMachine="yes" 
              Vital="yes" 
              SourceFile="$(var.PowerOnHybridWorkerConfigure.TargetDir)PowerOnHybridWorkerConfigure.exe" 
              DetectCondition="HybridWorkerConfigured" 
              UninstallCommand="Uninstall" />
```

Finally this is the code to restart the service, if I run the WPF exe outside of the bundle with admin rights then it works every time:

```
        public async Task<string> StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            return "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```